# Evenly distribute collection into new Arrays

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, language-agnostic

I'm trying to create an method to evenly distribute an array into X numbers of new arrays, where there is only allowed 15 items pr array, and you are only allowed to create a new array, if the previous have 10 items, except if the array has less than 10 items.

**EDIT**

*To make my question more understandable for future readers.*

- *This is just like a fabric.*
- *You need to build X number of products.*
- *One product takes T amount to build for an employee.*

*How many employees do you need and how do you share the work load between them?*

**END EDIT**

```
 Max allowed number in array = 15;
 Min allowed number in array = 10;    

 Number = Numbers of Items in the Collection.

 Number  5 =>   [5]
 Number 13 =>   [13]
 Number 16 =>   [10] [6]
 Number 29 =>   [15] [14]
 Number 30 =>   [15] [15]
 Number 31 =>   [11] [10] [10]
 Number 32 =>   [12] [10] [10]
 Number 33 =>   [11] [11] [11]
```

I'm trying to solve this in C#.

This is my code so far, but it fails at numbers like 16 = [16], 29 = [19][10], 38 = [18][10][10]

```
const int maxAllowedOrderLines = 15;
const int minAllowedOrderLines = 10;
var optimalOrderDisp = new List<int>();

Console.WriteLine("Number of OrderLines");
int linjer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

if (linjer <= maxAllowedOrderLines)
   optimalOrderDisp.Add(linjer);
else
{
   for (var i = maxAllowedOrderLines; i > 0; i--)
   {
      var maxOrderLines = linjer%i;
      if (maxOrderLines == 0 || i <= minAllowedOrderLines || linjer < maxAllowedOrderLines)
      {
         Console.WriteLine("Optimal number of order lines {0}--{1}", i, (double) linjer/(double) i);

          var optimalNumberOfOrders = linjer/i;
          for (var orderNumber = 0; orderNumber < optimalNumberOfOrders; orderNumber++)
          {
             optimalOrderDisp.Add(i);
          }

          if (maxOrderLines != 0)
             optimalOrderDisp[0] += maxOrderLines;
          break;
       }
    }
 }
 foreach (var i1 in optimalOrderDisp)
 {
    Console.Write("[{0}]", i1);
 }
 Console.WriteLine();
```

Comment: And you would want us to do what? Haw it fails? It looks like homework  :)

Comment: Why isn't 31 - `Number 31 => [15][10][6]` ?

Comment: #Adam Houldsworth Nope :-) It's been years since I was in school.

Comment: Ah - because it will always *try* to conform to the min/max constraints...

Comment: #El Ronnoco I added the failed output, hope it helps. About Number 31, your suggestion is not evenly distributed. Ex. with a Max = 30, your sorting would been [30][1]

Comment: Why is 38 = [18][10][10] and not 38 = [8][15][15] or 38 = [10][14][14]? Do you have any preference how it would be sorted? Would you rather try and keep new arrays at 10 items or 15?

Comment: @Dimitri I suppose the preference would be for "the least variance between all individual array sizes" - so in your example `[10][14][14]`... OP will have to confirm of course!

Comment: least variance would have been [12][13][13] isn't that right? And if you knew number of initial items you'd have to split, you could figure number of iterations for two loops that 1) create new arrays and 2) populate them

Comment: #El Ronnoco that's correct. Just looking for a way to spread it evenly. Think of it like work tasks. You wan't your people to have enough work, to keep them busy, but at the same time not have to much work, so that they can't handle it. And all the persons should have roughly the same amount of work.

Comment: @Dimitri Haha yes it would! I was just picking the least variance from your examples... We need more spec for this algorithm... For example if `min=1` then a perfectly even distribution could be `[1][1][1][1][1]... * total items`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Erm ...

```
const double bucketSize = 15.0;
var totalItems = (double)linjer;
var optimumBuckets = Math.Ceiling(totalItems / bucketSize);
var itemsPerBucket = (int)Math.Ceiling(totalItems / optimumBuckets);

var buckets = new int[(int)optimumBuckets];

var itemsLeft = (int)totalItems
for (var i = 0; i < buckets.length; i++)
{
    if (itemsLeft < itemsPerBucket)
    {
        buckets[i] = itemsLeft;
    }
    else
    {
        buckets[i] = itemsPerBucket;
    }
    itemsLeft -= itemsPerBucket;
}
```

seems to do what you want.

Comment: Notice he also has a lower limit for the bucket size - in his case 10. You solution does not account for that.

Comment: @SimonEjsing Its not necessary, unless you want to throw an exception if the condition cannot be satisfied.

Comment: the question says:
Number 16 =>   [10] [6] 
wouldn't your solution produce [8] [8]?

Comment: @Jodrell just testing it right now, and I looks like the lowest item count i could find is 8. So I think I'm going to use your solution, since its the most simple. Though Simon Ejsing solution produces the correct result.

Comment: @SimonEjsing you are correct. I think `[8] [8]` is a better answer but not to the exact question. I've voted accordingly.

Comment: I think `[8][8]` is a better answer too. If this is indeed about distributing work items then why would you have a minimum? What if you got 9 items of work in, would the OP have assigned all 9 to one team?

Answer (score 2):

Fun question. I've given it a go:

```
    const int maxAllowedOrderLines = 15;
    const int minAllowedOrderLines = 10;

    static List<int> optimalOrderDisp = new List<int>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int Lines = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        int MinNumberOfBuckets = (int) Math.Ceiling((double) Lines / minAllowedOrderLines);
        int RemainingLines = Lines;
        int BucketLines = Lines / MinNumberOfBuckets;

        // Distribute evenly
        for (int i = 0; i < MinNumberOfBuckets; i++)
        {
            optimalOrderDisp.Add(i != MinNumberOfBuckets - 1 ? BucketLines : RemainingLines);
            RemainingLines -= BucketLines;
        }

        // Try to remove first bucket
        while (RemoveBucket())
        {
        }

        // Re-balance
        Lines = optimalOrderDisp.Sum();
        RemainingLines = Lines;
        BucketLines = (int) Math.Round((double) Lines / (optimalOrderDisp.Count));
        for (int i = 0; i < optimalOrderDisp.Count; i++)
        {
            optimalOrderDisp[i] = (i != optimalOrderDisp.Count - 1 ? BucketLines : RemainingLines);
            RemainingLines -= BucketLines;
        }

        // Re-balance to comply to min size
        for (int i = 0; i < optimalOrderDisp.Count - 1; i++)
            if (optimalOrderDisp[i] < minAllowedOrderLines)
            {
                int delta = minAllowedOrderLines - optimalOrderDisp[i];

                optimalOrderDisp[i] += delta;
                optimalOrderDisp[optimalOrderDisp.Count - 1] -= delta;
            }

        Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\n", optimalOrderDisp.ToArray()));
    }

    static bool RemoveBucket()
    {
        if (optimalOrderDisp.Sum() > maxAllowedOrderLines * (optimalOrderDisp.Count - 1))
            return false;

        int Lines = optimalOrderDisp[0];
        int RemainingLines = Lines;
        int BucketLines = Lines / (optimalOrderDisp.Count - 1);

        // Remove bucket and re-distribute content evenly
        // Distribute evenly
        for (int i = 1; i < optimalOrderDisp.Count; i++)
        {
            optimalOrderDisp[i] += (i != optimalOrderDisp.Count - 1 ? BucketLines : RemainingLines);
            RemainingLines -= BucketLines;
        }

        optimalOrderDisp.RemoveAt(0);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Notice, I'm flipping it a bit around by pessimisticly distributing and then repeatedly removing buckets one by one if it will fit. It's probably not the optimal solution, but I tried the numbers you reported that were tricky and it works. My solution places the spare values in the last bucket. You can just flip the array if you need it to be in the first.